# Tracing NFS activity

Tags: networking, nfs

I've got a system of 55 workstations that share two NFS mount points on a central server.  Recently over the past few days, I've noticed an increasing number of "GETATTR" requests filtering in from the workstations for no apparent reason.  I can see these request clearly in a wireshark trace, but I don't know how to trace them down.

Can anybody share advice on how I can debug this problem and trace the generators of these calls?

**Update:** With trial and error, it turns out the GETATTRS were being caused by [preload](http://sourceforge.net/projects/preload/).  For the future, it would still be nice to know how I could determine what process is causing what NFS traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is mention [in this google doc (ala Red Hat)](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:4-ut1-nS7xoJ:www.redhat.com/f/pdf/rhel4/NFSv4WP.pdf+nfs+getattr&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESi_zgoJibMGV0iYMKkoLuWO0BIZEEWANlbmBuoV36WLaPCPlnNrWRxOH_C9leI6spxjXxFBV_o4trzvy0nZKIxsWJyMk_vgE0GXgkDRdyXve2BG5UhSyhHOnVlZP-3l_PRK3Q05&sig=AHIEtbQTN1HxbXmWXI2jtiTJxurTRZax9A) of the issue being caused by repeated open/close calls to files.  What kind of files are hosted on the share(s) and what kind of activity is being done with them?

Comment: Turns out the getaddrs were causes by 'preload' touching files every few minutes.